# defaultValue goes to null after editing other properties

Tags: ember.js

Got stuck again in the inside beauty of Ember.

I have the `posts` list, then the post's `view/creation` and also the post `edit`

You can see all the code [here](https://github.com/goblind/ember-bloggr-test/tree/master/public)

The model has its `date` property set to `defaultValue: new Date()` and the problems lies that when I edit an already created post, not just its date goes to null but every other posts too.
In short: I create a post and `date` is fine, I edit that post, reload the app, then all `dates` on all `posts` are null.

It's after `this.get('controller.model').save();` that the whole thing get messed up. And since the editing and creation of posts both share `post/edit.hbs` I rapidly thought "OK, so instead of handling the `save` in the `PostsRoute` I'd better do the "editing" one in the `PostController`. Well, that didn't work either.

I really don't get why `dates` are going null.

`routes.js` and `post_edit.hbs` should be the files to consider but everything's in the repository.

Thanks as always for any idea you may share with me.

Comment: Can you put together a jsBin or jsFiddle? That would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @chopper I'll do it first thing in the morning! thanks.